# What is the significance of having methods in a multithreaded program synchronized in real life

Tags: java, multithreading, object, synchronization

I'm aware of how multithreading and thread synchronization works in java but recently while studying about thread wait() and notify() methods I got everything confused and now I'm wondering what is the significance of making method synchronized.
 I've learnt that **"we use synchronized method so that no other thread can access that block of code on the same object "**. Here, **"on the same object"** seems quite unnatural to me.
 In these days more and more programs are following the object oriented approach and so they tend to do everything with objects so WHY DO WE WANT TO USE A SINGLE OBJECT(indirectly meaning the previous mention of **same object**) TO DO OUR WORK ?
Please explain me this concept with a real life example. The only example that I can find is that old bank account example where a husband and wife have a joint account and they are trying to do some modifications at the same time. Kindly take any other real life example.Thanks.
Update
I've added some code on github. In the code I'm unable to create a single instance of taxi class. Everytime I create a new thread a new instance of taxi is created.
 Here's my [code](https://github.com/shivamgeek/taxiExample)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you wish to book a taxi on a mobile app. So at a particular moment, app could assign that taxi only to one customer. Hence in this situation as well, you need synchronization so that taxi state remains consistent after transaction.

Comment: Here what is the object that I'm synchronizing ?

Comment: You should synchronize on the taxi instance you are trying to book

Comment: Thanks. That is a pretty easy and self explanatory example. Cleared much of my doubts but can you please also explain me where does methods wait() and notify() fit into this example, if possible :) .

Comment: Let's say twenty customer try to book taxi at same time, then only one of them (lets say customerA) will be allowed to go forward with booking and all others will wait on this taxi instance. Either customerA booking is done properly or booking attempt times out, then all other 19 customers should be notified to take next appropriate action.  Essentially, it depends on how you design the system, but one such usage could be as i mentioned

Comment: please have a look at my latest comment on @Arkantos(below) answer. Here how am I supposed to implement synchronization and wait(),notify() for 10 taxis(this example). Do I do need to create objects of all 10 taxis and synchronize them and call wait() and notify() on them appropriately individually ?

Comment: I've added a code on github github.com/shivamgeek/taxiExample. In this code I'm unable to create a single instance of taxi as everytime I run a new thread, a new instance of taxi is created. Please please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's not really mandatory to do synchronization in a multi-threaded program. It actually depends on our use case.

We'll synchronize a block of statements or a method only when that object has `shared mutable` state i.e the object is being shared among multiple threads and it's state is mutable.

Let's take a simple example of Train tickets. A train has a limited number of seats which can be booked by anyone using their site. If 2 people are trying to book tickets for same train, one of them has to acquire the lock first on the Train object, book their tickets and release the lock while the second person has to wait for the lock to be released. This way, changes done by the first person to the number of available seats are visible to next person waiting to book tickets. Without synchronization, we can never be sure about the reliability of the number of tickets.

So we do synchronization only on `Shared Mutable` objects. If the object that you're trying to acquire is not mutable, then no need to do synchronization.

Coming to `wait()` and `notify()`, these are low level APIs to communicate between multiple threads. The classic example of wait() & notify() is Thread Pools. Here's an excellent [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/) by Brian Goetz on these methods usage.

Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks. :) Just one small doubt. As u said that there are multiple people booking tickets for the same train, my question is that suppose there are such 10 trains train1,train2,train3....train10. Now in actual programming how will I synchronize each train. Do I need to synchronize methods such as book() for each train like synchronized (train1) book();  synchronized(train2) book(); synchrinized (train3)..  and so on.

Comment: Let's say you have Train class and each train has 100 seats. This seat class will have a method book(), and this book method will be  synchronized. There is no point locking the whole train just to book a particular seat. But again please note it depends totally on your design.  We are just trying to provide you an example and it need not necessarily be the design we are trying to demonstrate.

Comment: If we start synchronizing every method on our train object, that will be an over-kill. Instead of synchronizing all Trains, we synchronize `the means to book Trains`. Let's say any update to Train object happens  through a single object called `TrainService`. We will synchronize, blocks of code in that service using the Train object as lock whenever we query for no of seats and when we update the no of seats. That way you don't have to get a lock on all 10 trains. But we should be careful that all updates/queries for any Train happens through TrainService

Comment: @Arkantos I've added a code on github https://github.com/shivamgeek/taxiExample. In this code I'm unable to create a single instance of taxi as everytime I run a new thread, a new instance of taxi is created. Please please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's better to post a new question on that so that it'll get more visibility and likely to get more than just 2 opinions :) If you ask a new question in comments, only the 2 of us can reply.

Comment: Just saw your code. Your `Taxi` class doesn't have to extend Thread, as your `Customer` class does that already.